# Why passing 2D matrix gives error in C?

Tags: c

I have written this below simple code to demonstrate passing 2D matrix in C. I have gone through most of the online articles. And this code is inaccordance with those suggested approaches. But still I am getting a compile error. Please explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max = 0;

void maxId(int i,int j, int p[8][12]){


}

int main(){
    int m = 8;
    int n = 12;
    int p[m][n] = {{0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0},
                 {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1}};

    int v[m][n];

    for(int i= 0;i<m;i++)
        for(int j = 0;j<n;j++){
            v[i][j] = v[i][j];
        }

    maxId(0,0,p);
    return 0;
}
```

**Updated**

The compile error shown is

> 29    13  C:\Users\RainDrop\Documents\devc++
>   projects\Untitled2.cpp    [Error] cannot convert 'int (*)[n]' to 'int
>   (*)[12]' for argument '3' to 'void maxId(int, int, int (*)[12])'

Comment: What is the compilation error you are seeing?

Comment: When posting question about build error, please include the actual errors you get. In full, complete and unedited, and including any informational notes the compiler might have given. Preferably the complete build log. Also indicate (though a comment or such) Where in the source the erro(s) are.

Comment: Also, the expression `v[i][j] = v[i][j]` won't do anything useful.

Comment: Included the compile error message.

Comment: yes, actually I intended to uses `v = p` instead of `v = v`. But the compile error remains the same.

Comment: It doesn't like the fact that you're passing an `int [m][n]` to a function that wants an `int [8][12]`, even though `m` happens to be `8` and `n` happens to be `12` in this case.  So either make them both `int [8][12]`, or make them both `int [m][n]`.  In the latter case, you will need to pass `m` and `n` as additional parameters to `maxId`.

Comment: It seems that you are using C++ compiler to compile C code. Try switching on to a C one as the only "error" you should get here is for initializing an VLA.

Answer (score 5):

I see couple of problems:

1. A VLA, such as `p`, cannot be used as an argument to a function that expects a fixed size array. Imagine the problems if `m` is not `8` or `n` is not `12`.
2. A VLA cannot be initialized using an intializer list.

You can solve both problems by making `m` and `n` macros.

```
#define m 8
#define n 12
```

If you choose to do that, replace the use of the hard coded value `8` and `12` by `m` and `n`, respectively, everywhere.

**Update to point 1 above**

gcc does not mind if a VLA is used an argument in a function call where the expected argument type is fixed array. i.e. it is OK using `int (*)[n]` when the argument type is `int (*)[12]`. I have not been able to find anything in the standard that indicates which compiler is correct.

Comment: Just to clarify, a VLA is a variable length array.

Comment: Your first point is not quite valid I believe. If the number of elements of 2 array types are the same they are compatible. There is no requirements that says VLAs are not compatible with arrays (I don't think there is even such therm as fixed size arrays - which you used in your post, to distinguish them from VLAs).

Comment: There are possible "problems" but that is only when the array sizes doesn't match. However if they do - the behavior is perfectly defined I believe.

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD, re. the first point. The compiler error seen by the OP is related to that. `p` decays to type `int (*)[n]` while the expected argument type is `int (*)[12]`. It's possible some compilers allow it but it will lead to problems as soon as `n` is different from `12`.

Comment: @R Sahu *All compilers* conforming the standard (and the VLA arrays extension in it) should allow it. It's the programmer responsibility to make sure not invoke UB. And I was talking about your first point all the time. I don't know what your first response was meant for - passing argument to a function doesn't involve object initialization.

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD, sorry about the initialization point. I misunderstood.

Comment: @CisNOTthatGOODbutISOisTHATBAD I can't find anything in the C99 standard to indicate whether a VLA can be used as an argument to a function that expects a fixed size array. gcc does not seem to mind it

Answer (score 2):

To get around the issues mentioned by [*R Sahu*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37904469/694576), you can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void maxId(size_t m,size_t m, int p[m][n]){

}

#define M (8)
#define N (12)

int main(void)
{
  int p[M][N] = 
  {
    {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0},
    {0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1}
  };

  size_t n = N;
  size_t m = M;

  int v[m][n];

  for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
  {
    for(size_t j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      v[i][j] = p[i][j];
    }
  }

  maxId(m, n, v);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While running in devc++ it says compilation error. Andf the message is `5 41 C:\Users\RainDrop\Documents\devc++ projects\Untitled2.cpp [Error] use of parameter outside function body before ']' token`

Comment: @user3243499: Your question is tagged C *not* C++. The code compiles fine using a C compiler.

Comment: @user3243499: The error you quote refers to exactly *which* line of code, please?

Comment: ok. The error is shown for `void maxId(size_t m,size_t n, int p[m][n]` and the compile error message is `3 38 C:\Users\RainDrop\Documents\devc++ projects\Untitled2.cpp [Error] use of parameter outside function body before ']' token`. And while showing the error the cursor was at "m" in p[m][n]

Comment: Also, is there any specific reason that this code will only compiles using a C compiler and not a cpp compiler ?

Comment: @user3243499: "*... specific reason that this code will only compiles using a C compiler and not a C++ ....*": Yes, C and C++ are different languages. I think in C++ there are no VLAs. `p` in `maxId()`   and `v`  in `main()` are VLAs.